# Popen shell commands and | pipe symbol

Tags: android, python, shell, pipe, android-logcat

I have checked out numerous other threads with the same issue, but cannot get one that works for me. 
I am trying to run a command using the | character on a Windows machine, with python and wx.python. Command I'm trying to run is: adb.exe logcat | findstr myApp (stored in pkgName)

I have tried the following with no success, nothing is written in 'progressBox': note: they weren't all tried at the same time ;)

```
        logcat = subprocess.Popen(toolsDir + "\\adb.exe logcat", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        findstr = subprocess.Popen("findstr '"+ pkgName+"'", stdin=logcat.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = findstr.communicate()


        cmd = toolsDir+"\\adb.exe logcat | findstr " + pkgName
        ps = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        stdout = ps.communicate()[0]


        c_arg = 'logcat | findstr ' + pkgName
        params = toolsDir + "\\adb.exe " + c_arg
        p = Popen(params, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

They are all slightly different, but none append to my progressBox to print out the output.

```
        self.progressBox.AppendText(stdout)
        self.progressBox.AppendText(stderr)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have myself faced issue numerous times using subprocess library to run system command. I would probably recommend using core os library, still i am not very sure if this will work on windows but you could give a try.

```
import os
cmd = "ls -la > output.txt"
os.system(cmd)

reader = open("output.txt")
print(reader.read())
```

PS: It is recommended to use subprocess module to run system command, you should use above code only when you are unable to find a solution and just want to run code urgently.